# How to save image in data base loaded in ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using scroll view to load images in image view from array and then what ever image i want to save i am save to collection. So when i save image it always takes the pageNumber = 1 only  I want that what ever page when add it only adds page which is at number one not others

```
     -(void) loadNews{



      NSURL*myurl=url; 

     myurl = [myurl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
     myurl = [myurl stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]; 



    NSURL*urlloaded= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:myurl];


     NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlloaded];





   //Initialize the delegate.

    RowTwoParser *parser = [[RowTwoParser alloc] initXMLParser];

   //Set delegate

   [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];   
     BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

   if(success)

  NSLog(@"No Errors");

  else

   NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
  int k=0;
   for (int  i=0; i < [appDelegate.articles count]; i++) {

     currentIndex=i; 
     CGRect frame;
     frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
     frame.origin.y = 0;
     frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
     UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:frame];
     [self.scrollView addSubview:subView];
     RowTwo*aRowTwo=[appDelegate.articles objectAtIndex:i];



      CGRect mywebframe=CGRectMake(20, 60, 728, 800);

     UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:mywebframe];  


     NSString*thumb2=aRowTwo.image;



      thumb2 = [thumb2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
      thumb2 = [thumb2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


          NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:thumb2];
         NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

       imageView.image =image2 ; 

      [subView addSubview:imageView];

        }  




    //NSInteger numberofPages=10-j;
     NSInteger numberofPages=[appDelegate.articles count];
       self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width *   numberofPages, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    CGRect frame;
  //frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
     frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * myindex;
       frame.origin.y = 0;
       frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
      [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];



     [pageControl setNumberOfPages:numberofPages];
     [pageControl setActivePageColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [pageControl setInactivePageColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  

     }
  -(IBAction)addToCollectionButtonAction{




    GeoNewsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (GeoNewsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  // Create a Coffee Object.
  Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0];

  int pageNumber  = [pageControl currentPage]; 
  NSLog(collectionImage);


  RowTwo*aRowTwo=[appDelegate.articles objectAtIndex:pageNumber];




    NSString*thumb2=aRowTwo.image;

   coffeeObj.thumb = thumb2;
  coffeeObj.path = thumb2; 





     [appDelegate addCoffee:coffeeObj];



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable paging for scroll view

self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES

Comment: I have done like thsi but again it shows value 1 of pageControl.currentPage

Comment: UIScrollView Paging Not working well--- your ques is this one right? code is not understandable, write each mthd with a short notes..

Comment: Paging is workin fine but my question is this that for e.g your are on page 2 and you click add button to add that image in collections. there it does not save the image of that page but save of page1

Comment: you will be knowing the frame/page size in scroll view right? implement delegate for scrollView, check offset of scrollView and set the pageNumber to PageControl..

    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView